# Negate number without using +, * and -

Tags: java

Is it possible to negate a number without using +,* and - operator.
I know it can be done using BigDecimal negate() Function.
Is it possible to do with out using external libraries.

For ex:
int n = 9
Output:
-9

Comment: Probably `(int)(~0 & (~n))` will bring you very close...

Comment: is it possible to get  exact match..

Comment: It's an exact match for odd values, and a near-exact for even values.

Comment: @ goodvibration thanks for your valuable answer. but i want a exact match.. i am also trying to google to get exact match but coudn't make it.pls let me know if you find any... :)

Comment: if you can accept an 'indirect' `+`, then `(int) ~0 & ~n + 1` would work.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know, there is no java method for this.

So your options are to built it yourself by simply multiply by -1.
Or use another library.

```java
public class NumberUtils {
    public static int negate(int i) {
        return i * -1;
    }
}
```

Using this Utils class would look like:

```java
public class NumberUtilsTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Integer i = new Integer(9);
      int i2 = 9;
      System.out.println(NumberUtilsTest.negate(i)); // prints -9
      System.out.println(NumberUtilsTest.negate(i2)); // prints -9
  }
}
```

Comment: There are both `*` and `-` in that expression. And the question asks for a trick which doesn't make use of the arithmetic operators specified, not whether or not "there is a Java method for that". Obviously the Java language doesn't provide a built-in function for such a purpose. And in any case, the fact that "as far as you know there isn't" doesn't mean that is indeed the case. So I can't quite see any added value in your answer.

Comment: i want answer with out using *(multiplication),-(subraction) and +(addition).

Answer (score -1):

If you are just looking for a util method you can use [`Math.negateExact()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#negateExact-int-):

```
int n = Math.negateExact(9);
```

The result will be `-9`.

Internally `Math.negateExact()` uses just `-`:

```
public static int negateExact(int a) {
    if (a == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        throw new ArithmeticException("integer overflow");
    }
    return -a;
}
```

Comment: @aravindhan Doesnt matter that `Math.negateExact()` also uses "-"?

Comment: @Sunchezz Yes that is correct, I just wanted to add this info. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @Samuel Philipp : actually i was attending program contest.. in that they asked this question... i will share you question.... "Given a positive number (>=1) N, Write a function that returns negative of number, but you aren't allowed to use +, * or - operator in any form."

Comment: so in my program i am not using  +, * or - operator in any form.so it works

Comment: @aravindhan I'm glad you solved your problem. Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it was useful to you.